# node.js HTTP request with automatic ntlm / kerberos authentication

Tags: node.js, ntlm, node-request

Looking through npm all ntlm / kerberos modules seem to want a hard coded username and password when performing HTTP requests against a windows authenticated endpoint.

Is it possible to use the credentials of the currently logged in user?

e.g. In PowerShell I can do this:

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
```

Would this be at all possible with node?

Comment: did you find a solution, and, which modules is it you found already?... (We might be able to accept the hardcoded user/pass)... And I am looking for such solution.

Comment: Didn't find a solution for what I was trying to do. Maybe getting node to execute a PowerShell script which does the request might be a away to go

Answer (score 1):

NTLM and Kerberos authentication are possible with node-expose-sspi.

https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi

Note : I am the author of node-expose-sspi.